# Microsoft Project Automation Rename Field

Tags: automation, ms-project

I have been working on a complex integration to Microsoft Project using c#.

I have achieve almost everything I need to do but have one issue that I am struggling to find a way to do. I need to add some custom columns to the plan and have achieved this by using additional columns such as 'Text1', but need to rename the column to be more meaningful. This is easy in project itself but I can't currently seen the correct part of the API to do this. Any pointers much appreciated.